# Modify the page layout of application materials (i.e. A4 vs. Letter) when applying for jobs in multiple countries?

Tags: job-search, application, international, formatting

Most countries use A4 paper. The US and Canada use letter paper. When applying for jobs across several countries should application materials always be designed to meet the page layout norms for the particular job location? Will materials even be printed?

Comment: That's why I like writing in LaTeX..

Comment: Well, in principle yes, but if you have a strange CV format that does things with the margins, including "a4paper" or "letterpaper" will not work as it is intended.

Comment: Thx. Any opinion on this from other people who participated in search commitees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Question 1:** When applying for jobs across several countries should application materials always be designed to meet the page layout norms for the particular job location?

I had never even considered doing this and I would not bother trying to change the paper format. If you do not change it, software will shrink the text to fit when it is printed. It might not look ideal but it is the content that matters. I can't imagine that anybody is going to hold the fact that you come from an A4 using country against you. If you do change it, probably nobody will notice.

> **Question 2:** Will materials even be printed?

I was just on a search committee. Every single member of the committee brought a laptop or tablet to the meeting. No printouts. When the shortlisted candidates were forwarded to the full department, I noticed that some people on the full faculty had printed out application materials. So, maybe?

Comment: Thx for the answer. Any opinion on this from other people who participated in search commitees?